# Python program that checks whether a specified value is contained in group of values

Tags: python

```
value1=list(input("First value:"))


group1=[]


list_size1=int(input("How many characters do you want in first group1:"))
for i in range(0,list_size1):
    print("Enter number at index",i,)
    item1=int(input())
    group1.append(item1)


for i in range(0,len(value1)-1):
    if value1[0]==group1[i]:
        continue
    print("True")
```

But my code doesn't work properly.I have no errors but i don't get the answer correctly.If I use my first value in first element of group 1 i have no problem but if i used it on other elemts it doesn't show True even my number is in group1.What should I do?

Comment: You have to use two for loops one to loop through values1 and other through group1 to and check if the value is available. Moreover, the group1[i] is looped over in second for loop but the value1[0] is not, it always will return you the first element in that list.

Comment: A short way to check if a list contains a certain value, you can use `in` such as in a for loop: `3 in [4, 99, 3]` returns `True` whilst `3 in [1, 99, 2]`returns `False`. Following that pattern, you can check your group without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `in` operator to check if a value is in a sequence.

```
>>> "a" in "abc"
True

>>> 1 in [1,2,3]
True
```

so try with

```
if value1[0] in group1
```

Anyway, the error i can see is that you are grabbing the length of value1 in your for loop then using that as a index to group1.

```
for i in range(0,len(value1)-1): # here you take len(value1), you probably wanted len(group1)
    if value1[0]==group1[i]:
        continue
    print("True")
```

You can loop the group1 directly instead of looping the index:

```
for item in group1:
    if value1[0] == item:
        continue
    print("True")
```

Now the continue part, it actually skips any items that matches, *the opposite of what you are asking for*.

To check if any of the values in value1 is contained within group1:

```
for value in value1:
  if value in group1:
    print("True")
    break
```

If value1 is always just a single input, skip the list() part of the first row and just do

```
>>> value1 = input("First value: ")
First value: a

>>> value1
a

>>> group = list(input("group of stuff: "))
group of stuff: abcd

>>> group
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

>>> value1 in group
True
```